# NumPy producing different results in Ubuntu and RHEL

Tags: numpy, ubuntu, rhel

I am facing a platform reproducibility issue with NumPy. My development environment is in RHEL Linux and production is in PCF Cloud (Ubuntu).
below calculation is giving different result in RHEL and Ubuntu.

```
a=np.log(np.float32(0.042230162769556046)/np.float32(0.9577698111534119))
```

Result in RHEL: -3.1214728
Result in Ubuntu: -3.1214726

I see the floating point re producibility across platform is an issue. Any suggestions on how to handle this will be great help.

Comment: Maybe this [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18371). I remember a similar question where changes to an underlying Linux library give slightly different results, but I can't find it.

Comment: You could try `print(np.show_config())` and look for differences.

Comment: np.show_config() giving exact same results in both the platforms. in fact processor also exact same, only difference is Linux distribution.